# SharePoint Partition Warning

Tags: sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search, index-partition

My SharePoint Search is suddenly not working. I have tried restarting services/clearing cache and restarting server but I still have this:
[image]

I also have the search stck on paused and All Errors:
[image]

And the Powershell command never seems to end:

```
PS C:\Users\SPFarmSvc> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
PS C:\Users\SPFarmSvc> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "SharePoint_Search_Service"
PS C:\Users\SPFarmSvc> Resume-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $ssa
```

Sometimes I even get red crosses as below:
[image]

I even tried the below but the status is stuck on paused and showing All Errors:
[image]

Event Logs shows this error for VSS:

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine
>   RegOpenKeyExW(-2147483646,SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VSS\Diag,...).
>   hr = 0x80070005, Access is denied. .
>
> Operation:    Initializing Writer
>
> Context:    Writer Class Id: {0ff1ce15-0201-0000-0000-000000000000}
>   Writer Name: OSearch15 VSS Writer    Writer Instance Name: OSearch15
>   Replication Service    Writer Instance ID:
>   {983a2893-68e6-42ed-9e42-932f132b9257

Yet when I checked the registry keys VSS seemed to have the correct permissions:
[image]

```
#########################################################################
# Enterprise Search Deployment Script
# -----------------------------------
# Deploys Enterprise Search to a traditional, three-server SharePoint
# 2013 farm (1 App, 2 WFE), and configures it with the following
# application topology:
# 
# Server Role       Search Components
# -----------       --------------------
# Application       Admin
#           Crawler
#           Content Processing
#           Analytics Processing
# WFEs          Query Processing
#           Index Partition
#
# Acknowledgements
# ----------------
# This script is based upon that originally published by Ryan Bushnell
# in his 7 August 2013 blog post, "SharePoint 2013 Search Configuration 
# PowerShell Script".  I've made minor tweeks to it in order to extend
# it to a three-server topology. To use the script below, replace
# bracketed values with those appropriate to your own farm.
# Many thanks to Ryan for making search deployment much more 
# automated and consistent.
#
# Notes
# -----
# 1) I use the traditional search service account both for search
# administration and for query processing.
# 2) The D drive is configured as the data drive on all farm servers.
#
# Stephan Albert Bren
# May 17, 2014.
##########################################################################


#Setup Variables
#---------------
#Assume 3 Accounts (Content Access, Admin, Query)
#### Note - You should setup the Index Location prior to running these commands and ensure it is an empty folder
#### Note - If you setup diag logging prior to running script, ensure you give dbo permissions to the account you run this under
write-host 0. Setting up some initial variables.




$AppSvr = "server 1"
$WebSvr1 = "server 1"
$WebSvr2 = "server 2"

$CAAcct = "servivce acc"
$password = "***"
$CAAcctPW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force

$AdminAcct = service acc"
$QueryAcct = "service acc"
$SSAName = "Search_Service"
$DBPrefix = "SP_Search"

$SSIAppSvr = get-SPServiceInstance -server $AppSvr |?{$_.TypeName -eq "SharePoint Server Search"}
$SSIWebSvr1 = get-SPServiceInstance -server $WebSvr1 |?{$_.TypeName -eq "SharePoint Server Search"}
$SSIWebSvr2 = get-SPServiceInstance -server $WebSvr2 |?{$_.TypeName -eq "SharePoint Server Search"}

$IndexLocation = "C:\Scripts\search_data"
$err = $null
 
 
#Start Services for SSI
#----------------------
write-host 1. Start Services search services for Each Server

Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $SSIAppSvr
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $SSIWebSvr1
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $SSIWebSvr2
 

#Create Application Pools
#------------------------
write-host 2. Create a Application Pools

#$AdminAppPool = new-SPServiceApplicationPool -name   $SSAName"-AdminAppPool" -account $AdminAcct 
#$QueryAppPool = new-SPServiceApplicationPool -name   $SSAName"-QueryAppPool" -account $QueryAcct

$AdminAppPool = new-SPServiceApplicationPool -name   $SSAName" AppPool" -account $AdminAcct 
$QueryAppPool = $AdminAppPool
 

#Create Search Service Application
#---------------------------------
write-host 3. Create the SearchApplication and set it to a variable

$SearchApp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name $SSAName -applicationpool $AdminAppPool -databasename $DBPrefix"_AdminDB"
 
 
#Create Search Service Application Proxy
#---------------------------------------
write-host 4. Create search service application proxy

$SSAProxy = new-spenterprisesearchserviceapplicationproxy -name $SSAName" Application_Proxy" -SearchApplication $SearchApp
 
 
#Clone Search Topology (this is empty by default)
#------------------------------------------------
write-host 5. Clone Search Topology

$SearchTopology = $SearchApp.ActiveTopology.Clone()
 
 
#Provision Search Administration Component
#-----------------------------------------
write-host 6. Provision Search Admin Component.

New-SPEnterpriseSearchAdminComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIAppSvr -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
 
 
#Provision New Search Content Processing Component
#-------------------------------------------------
write-host 7. Create New Search Content Processing Component

New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentProcessingComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIAppSvr -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentProcessingComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr2 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
 
 
#Provision New Search Analytics Processing Component
#---------------------------------------------------
write-host 8. Create New Search Analytics Processing Component

New-SPEnterpriseSearchAnalyticsProcessingComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIAppSvr -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
New-SPEnterpriseSearchAnalyticsProcessingComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr2 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
 
 
#Provision New Search Crawl Component
#------------------------------------
write-host 9. Create New Search Crawl Component

New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIAppSvr -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr2 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
 
#Provision New Search Index Component
#------------------------------------
write-host 10. Create New Search Index Component

New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr1 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology -RootDirectory $IndexLocation
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr2 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology -RootDirectory $IndexLocation
 

#Provison New Query Processing Component
#---------------------------------------
write-host 11. Create New Query Processing Component
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr1 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr2 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology
  
#Activate Topology Changes
#-------------------------
write-host 12. Activate Topology
$SearchTopology.Activate()
 
 
#Setup default Content Access Account
#------------------------------------
write-host 13. Set the default content access account

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication –Identity $SearchApp -ApplicationPool $QueryAppPool -DefaultContentAccessAccountName $CAAcct -DefaultContentAccessAccountPassword $CAAcctPW
 
#Finish
#------
Write-host "Your search application $SSAName is now ready"
```

Comment: You need to review the ULS logs to see what is the error when you try to start. There should be something logged. I would review as well the event viewers on the servers that hold the partition.

Comment: I get this error (check edit above)

Comment: It may be red herring, are you using shadow copy service on your storage?  What you get in ULS?

Comment: I recreated the search. the status is now running however the searchable items is still giving all errors, and index partition still has an exclamation mark

Comment: If you recreated the search, and there is still problem with index partition there might be a problem with disk itself. try to create a new search web app (Leave the original one) and try to create index partition on different drive, even on C for test to see does this works.

Comment: You mean change the index location for write-host 10. Create New Search Index Component

New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr1 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology -RootDirectory $IndexLocation
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchServiceInstance $SSIWebSvr2 -SearchTopology $SearchTopology -RootDirectory $IndexLocation?

Comment: You could do that as well. I meant to create a new search web app (you can have more than one on the farm)

Comment: i created a new one it still has the same issues - pasted the script im using above

Comment: Do you get any errors in SharePoint ULS logs during this setup?

Comment: what should I look for? I deleted and recreated the search a third time and it still gets created with degraded partition I am running out of options

Comment: you need to review ULS logs for errors. Get the ULS log viewer and use filter 'show errors only' and feed it with logs from the time you were provisioning the search application.